# Create SQL table with contents of two tables with different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data logs from a machine that I would like to combine into a single table. However older data logs have different columns than newer ones (certain variables were added/tracked later on).

I mocked up an example in Excel that I am trying to mimic in my Microsoft SQL database. I can't determine the query to use.

Thank you for any help!

EDITS: 
1. I don't think this is a duplicate.
2. How many data logs? ~100 data log tables.
3. I am using MS SQL
4. I would prefer not to have to type out all the column names if possible, there are many.

[Excel Diagram Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3JoC.png)

Comment: How many different data logs are we talking about? 1, 5, 10, 100?

Comment: MySQL and ms sql server are two different products. Which one do you use?

Comment: Also, check out the `union` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UNION`

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
   date, 
   tim, 
   val1, 
   val2, 
   val3 
from dataset1 
union all
SELECT 
   date, 
   tim, 
   val1, 
   '' as val2, 
   val3 
 From dataset2
```

This will get the data from the 2 tables and null values in the `dataset2` table where the column not exist.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without listing out all the columns? Some sort of wildcard method?

Comment: @Hi_Im_E no - you have to identify the columns explicitly if they are different.

Comment: @DStanley if that is the case is there a query I can run to list out all the columns, comma seperated, so I can copy and paste?

Comment: @Hi_Im_E if the tables have the same amount of columns you can use select *. If not, you need to list them all.